# Can every signature scheme be transformed into a public-key encryption scheme?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

I am reading about Signing vs. Public-Key encryption and a question pop up in mind that is it possible to transform any signature scheme to a public-key encryption scheme?

Comment: A possible duplicate and a more strong question [Reduction from signatures to encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/148/reduction-from-signatures-to-encryption)

Answer (score 2):

**No**, we know no general way to build a public-key encryption scheme from a signature scheme.

And accordingly, we have some signature schemes with no known way to build a public-key encryption scheme from the same primitives. An example is the [eXtended Merkle Signature Scheme](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/484), built from symmetric hash and PRF.

<sub>[It was not asked, but: I learned from [Maeher's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/188474) that we *can* build a signature scheme from any public key encryption scheme. And I can't tell from memory a public-key encryption scheme that does not have a related  signature scheme built from similar primitives or underlying problem(s)].</sub>

Comment: You *can* build signature schemes from any public key encryption scheme. PKE implies one-way functions and we know how to construct signature schemes using nothing but one-way functions.

Answer (score 1):

No, although some signature schemes are built from public key encryption schemes, others are not.

For example, the [Lamport Signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_signature) scheme.

A few of the signature schemes submitted to the NIST post-quantum project are also hash based, like [SPHINCS+](https://sphincs.org/data/sphincs+-specification.pdf).

Comment: This answers the non-trivially-equivalent question: are all signature schemes built from a public-key encryption scheme?